# JBoss AS 7 And Java 1.7 running slow with debugger Turned OFF

Tags: garbage-collection, jboss7.x, java-7

I encounter weird issue this with jboss as 7 running with jvm 1.7._029. When I turned OFF following from standalone.conf, jboss takes 7x longer to deploy as well as 7x times longer to serve request.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Request that takes normally 2sec now takes around 15 - 20 sec! If I turned on above option than both jboss deployment and request serving becomes faster. We usually have it turned on in Dev so we never experienced it until we turned it off in staging.

Xms and Xmx settings have no effect on above obervations.

I did some profiling with VisualVM. Only a single instance of jboss and only one client thread making request. Heap profiling indicates that when debugger is turned on It preallocates good chunk of heap out of Xms setting upon boot. i.e lets say Xms is 1g then it says "Heap Size" 1G and "Used Heap" 750mb. From then on it starts jboss quickly and it flacuate very little when request is made sequentially.

While running with debugger turned off, initial "Heap Size" is still at 1G but "Used Heap" is pretty low and then it tries to allocate more memory midway during deployment and eventually after a while it completes deployment. Upon new request it does same thing again. i.e allocate and de-allocates memory at runtime.

```
java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+PrintGCDetails -version
```

-XX:InitialHeapSize=268435456 -XX:MaxHeapSize=4294967296 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+**UseParallelGC** 
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 76800K, used 2642K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007b0000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 66048K, 4% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007aad14878,0x00000007aeb00000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000007af580000,0x00000007af580000,0x00000007b0000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000007aeb00000,0x00000007aeb00000,0x00000007af580000)
 ParOldGen       total 174592K, used 0K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000070aa80000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 174592K, 0% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000700000000,0x000000070aa80000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 2119K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x00000006fc300000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 21504K, 9% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006fb011da0,0x00000006fc300000)

JBoss Process:

```
/usr/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+**TieredCompilation** -Dprogram.name=standalone.sh -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11090 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
```

Comment: did you check ThreadDump in both condition? Check if any additional thread is running.

Comment: most probably it would have additional thread to run debugger. Anyhow I switched to Spring-boot with my beloved web container tomcat. I hope never to look back on to jboss on any app server :)